# Audacity weird error

Tags: audacity

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux) and Audacity 2.3.1

Each time I try to record a new track, with another track already recorded, the software crashes and gives me an errors message and report (which I can not to ulpoad here, because I don't know how to do it).

Example:

I import an audio...

[image]

Then... I try to record a new track and press the Record red button and, inmediately, I get this...

[image]

I can add the following information from the Linux Reports:

---

Process 22044 (audacity) of user 1000 dumped core.

Stack trace of thread 22054:

## 0  0x0000562779123980 n/a (n/a)

Process 22044 (audacity) crashed and dumped core.

This usually indicates a programming error in the crashing program and
should be reported to its vendor as a bug.

---

BTW: I can confirm that it is a local issue. Same software, with the same configuration, doesn't show this error issue in my other computers, just in this one... But... Why???

How can I fix it?

Comment: I see that you are running 2.3.1 of Audacity - is this installed via snap or PPA?  I can't duplicate this issue with Audacity 2.2.2, and would suggest that you report this as a bug over at [Panda Jim's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity) (if that's where you got 2.3.1), or on the Audacity Team Forum [https://forum.audacityteam.org/](https://forum.audacityteam.org/)

Comment: I don't know whether this issue is a bug or a user error without looking at a screenshot of the two tracks open side by side in Audacity. Please upload a screenshot and provide a link to it in a comment, so that it can be embedded into your question.

Comment: I uploaded two screenshot to the main text.

Comment: I think I fixed it!!! I just copied the folders: .audacity.data and usr/share/audacity from one of the other computers (where Audacity works so fine) to this "problematic" computer, and... Now Audacity is working so fine in this computer! So... I guess there was something missed here (I don't know what). But... I'm not sure if this is a "final" solution. Whatever... I hope it will be useful to someone else.